KPack - Builder resource creation failed following the tutorial
I am getting started with kpack and following the tutorial steps listed here
Unfortunately Builder resource creation with message

message: 'validating buildpack
paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates@3.8.2: stack
io.buildpacks.stacks.jammy is not supported'   status: "False"  Could
not get more information other than this.

Not sure what is causing the error. Appreciate your time and help
thanks
Here is the Builder menfiest
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: kpack.io/v1alpha2
  kind: Builder
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"kpack.io/v1alpha2","kind":"Builder","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"ecr-builder","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"order":[{"group":[{"id":"paketo-buildpacks/java"}]},{"group":[{"id":"paketo-buildpacks/nodejs"}]}],"serviceAccountName":"service-account","stack":{"kind":"ClusterStack","name":"base"},"store":{"kind":"ClusterStore","name":"default"},"tag":"1234567890.xx.xx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/project/repo:builder03"}}
    creationTimestamp: "2024-07-01T03:23:46Z"
    generation: 1
    name: ecr-builder
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "1982966141"
    uid: 846605da-fe38-4163-a242-92fc4735cf48
  spec:
    order:
    - group:
      - id: paketo-buildpacks/java
    - group:
      - id: paketo-buildpacks/nodejs
    serviceAccountName: service-account
    stack:
      kind: ClusterStack
      name: base
    store:
      kind: ClusterStore
      name: default
    tag: 1234567890.xx.xx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/project/repo:builder03
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastTransitionTime: "2024-07-01T03:23:47Z"
      message: 'validating buildpack paketo-buildpacks/ca-certificates@3.8.2: stack
        io.buildpacks.stacks.jammy is not supported'
      status: "False"
      type: Ready
    observedGeneration: 1
    stack: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  
---
apiVersion: kpack.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterStack
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"kpack.io/v1alpha2","kind":"ClusterStack","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"base"},"spec":{"buildImage":{"image":"paketobuildpacks/build-jammy-base"},"id":"io.buildpacks.stacks.jammy","runImage":{"image":"paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-07-01T03:21:13Z"
  generation: 1
  name: base
  resourceVersion: "1982962342"
  uid: 6466a2d7-7869-46f2-a202-bcce42764a93
spec:
  buildImage:
    image: paketobuildpacks/build-jammy-base
  id: io.buildpacks.stacks.jammy
  runImage:
    image: paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base
status:
  buildImage:
    image: paketobuildpacks/build-jammy-base
    latestImage: index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/build-jammy-base@sha256:5925b2c144a8a0123621899d32ca39a6ba52a078c9edeb06f14431610e3a6c03
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2024-07-01T03:21:14Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  groupId: 1000
  id: io.buildpacks.stacks.jammy
  observedGeneration: 1
  runImage:
    image: paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base
    latestImage: index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/run-jammy-base@sha256:a1046306c5f4fa044692283380a7a91e2fedfb035df9dd0f6b54948003357315
  userId: 1001


Due to this. Looks like its fixed in 3.8.3
